# Using array in different methods

Tags: c#, function, methods

well i'm doing a code in C#,
this code allows you to add items to your code, price, unit, etc. save them in an array, and a menu will display the aggregated items.
I have a problem because I do it this way and apparently my code don't work, could someone help me?.
King Regards.
I'm newest in this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Market
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public static int item { get; set; }
        public static string[] product = new string[item];
        public static string[] code = new string[item];
        public static  string[] price = new string[item];
        public static string[] unit = new string[item];

        public void showMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1.- Add new item");
            Console.WriteLine("2.- Show items");
            Console.WriteLine("3.- Exit");
            //Menu 
            while (true)
            {
                string option = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (option)
                {
                    case "1":
                        addItem();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        showItems();
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.Environment.Exit(-1);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Select one valid option..");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        public static void addItem()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAmount of items to add");
            item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert the items.");
            for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nItem[" + i + "]: ");
                Console.Write("Product[" + i + "]: ");
                product[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Code[" + i + "]: ");
                code[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Price[" + i + "]: ");
                price[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Unit[" + i + "]: ");
                unit[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        public static void showItems()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("******* SHOW ITEMS *******");
            Console.WriteLine("Product ------------- Code ------------- Price ------------- Unit");
            for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(product[i] + "                 " + code[i] + "                    " + price[i] + "                     " + unit[i]);
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: `I have a problem because I do it this way and apparently my code don't work,` What is the problem and what you meant by `don't work`

Comment: In addition to @un-lucky comment -  please read something about classes... having 4 arrays to represent single entity is very questionable approach.

Comment: Not intending to pile on, but this is an example (and solution) of Alexei's comment https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Comment: From your code, it seems using list is better as you want a resizeable collection.

Answer (score 3):

There are few problems with the code.

1. Arrays that you created for product, code, etc are of *zero* size as `item` value is by default. Inserting any value to `0` sized array throws an exception.
2. Also you should be cautious on accessing the static fields in not static context.
   .

I would suggest define a class with these properties and use the `List` to keep collection.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public int Unit {get;set;}  
}
```

Now modify your `additem` to create products.

```
    public static void addItem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nAmount of items to add");
        item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert the items.");
        for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
        {
            var product = new Product();
            Console.WriteLine("\nItem[" + i + "]: ");
            Console.Write("Product[" + i + "]: ");
            product.Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Code[" + i + "]: ");
            product.Code = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Price[" + i + "]: ");
            product.Price = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  //read as double value.

            Console.Write("Unit[" + i + "]: ");
            product.Unit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Read as int value

            products.Add(product); // products is global/class variable.
        }
    }
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GeMCTG), it gives you an idea to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing yours arrays with a zero length. You arrays and item property are static that are initializing at application start. So when you change item field your arrays have already been initialized with default value of int, that is zero. You should initialize your arrays after setting the item property. And even after this you will not be able to add items to your arrays. Try to use List<> instead.

Comment: And according to comments be careful using static in non static context and better solution would be a creating a class to describe item and use List<> to store them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the static variable `item` is initialized to 0 when the class loads. Once you change it by reading in the user inputted value, you don't allocate properly sized arrays for your static variables. You can fix this by doing so after reading in the value:

```
public static void addItem()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nAmount of items to add");
    item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // initialize static vars to correct size, now that we have #items
    product = new string[item];
    code = new string[item];
    price = new string[item];
    unit = new string[item];

    Console.WriteLine("Insert the items.");
    for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nItem[" + i + "]: ");
        Console.Write("Product[" + i + "]: ");
        product[i] = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Code[" + i + "]: ");
        code[i] = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Price[" + i + "]: ");
        price[i] = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Unit[" + i + "]: ");
        unit[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

You can see the fixed code in action at https://dotnetfiddle.net/n5lWTQ !

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started... you instantiated your `arrays` in the field declaration with a size of `item`

```
    public static int item { get; set; }
    public static string[] product = new string[item];
    public static string[] code = new string[item];
    public static string[] price = new string[item];
    public static string[] unit = new string[item];
```

The problem with this is that the moment you access the `Menu` class, these lines of code immediately gets executed. And since the `default` value of an `int` is `0`, you will have your array sizes to be 0. Try applying breakpoints into those line and you'll see.

Now what you can do here is instantiate them once you have set the value of `item`. So you will have your code to be something like this...

```
    public static int item { get; set; }
    //just declare your arrays here
    public string[] product;
    public string[] code;
    public string[] price;
    public string[] unit;

    public void addItem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nAmount of items to add");
        item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //instantiate your arrays here since item will have a value you have set it into.
        product = new string[item];
        code = new string[item];
        price = new string[item];
        unit = new string[item];

        Console.WriteLine("Insert the items.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a list of objects containing the required fields of your item. A generic list will allow you to dynamically add items to the list without having to set the size during initialization. This means you can add items (using option 1) as many times as you like without changing the arrays.

In addition to setting the arrays to zero size when you initialized your class (as other answers have suggested), it looked as if you were re-using your `int item` property each time you wanted to add new items to your lists. This means that the variable was changing so your `ShowItems()` method did not function correctly.

Here is a working example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Market
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public struct Item
        {
            public string product;
            public string code;
            public string price;
            public string unit;
        }
        public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        public static void showMenu()
        {
            //Menu 
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n1.- Add new item");
                Console.WriteLine("2.- Show items");
                Console.WriteLine("3.- Exit");

                string option = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (option)
                {
                    case "1":
                        addItem();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        showItems();
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.Environment.Exit(-1);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Select one valid option..");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        public static void addItem()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAmount of items to add");
            int numbItemsToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  // needs validation
            Console.WriteLine("Insert the items.");
            for (int i = 0; i < numbItemsToAdd; i++)
            {
                Item item = new Item();
                Console.WriteLine("\nItem[" + (i + 1) +"]: ");
                Console.Write("Product[" + (i + 1) +"]: ");
                item.product = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Code[" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
                item.code = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Price[" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
                item.price = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Unit[" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
                item.unit = Console.ReadLine();

                items.Add(item);
            }

        }

        public static void showItems()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("******* SHOW ITEMS *******");
            Console.WriteLine("Product ------------- Code ------------- Price ------------- Unit");

            foreach(Item i in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.product + "                " + i.code + "                   " + i.price + "                    " + i.unit);
            }
        }



        public static void Main()
        {
            showMenu();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Menu
  {
    public static int item { get; set; }
    public static List<string> product = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> code = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> price = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> unit = new List<string>();

    public void showMenu()
    {
        //Menu 
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n1.- Add new item");
            Console.WriteLine("2.- Show items");
            Console.WriteLine("3.- Exit \n");

            string option = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (option)
            {
                case "1":
                    addItem();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    showItems();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    System.Environment.Exit(-1);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Select one valid option..");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void addItem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nAmount of items to add");
        item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert the items.");
        for (int i = 1; i <= item; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nItem[" + i + "]: ");
            Console.Write("Product[" + i + "]: ");
            product.Add(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Code[" + i + "]: ");
            code.Add(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Price[" + i + "]: ");
            price.Add(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Unit[" + i + "]: ");
            unit.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    }

    public static void showItems()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("******* SHOW ITEMS *******");
        Console.WriteLine("Product ------------- Code ------------- Price ------------- Unit");
        for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product[i] + "                 " + code[i] + "                    " + price[i] + "                     " + unit[i]);
        }
    }
}
```